# MuleSoft changes Decimal value when reading excel file

Tags: dataweave, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, anypoint-platform

I am reading an Excel (.xlsx) file in MuleSoft from AWS S3 bucket and once I have the file from S3 bucket, I get the data of the excel file like this :

```
 %dw 2.0
output application/json

---

payload.parts pluck (value,key,index) -> 
        {
            (key) : { (read(value.content, 'application/xlsx'))} 
        }
```

the problem is, there is a value in file **12.535**, which is being read as **12.53499999**. Which creates a problem in rounding because ideally when I round up the decimal I should get value **12.54** but instead because of that `.5349999`I get value as **12.53**.

How can I make sure Mule reads correct value or parses a correct value?

using Mule runtime 4.3.0.

Comment: Are you certain that the actual value in the field is not actually 12.53499999 but because of the formatting on Excel you see it rounded to two decimals?

Comment: yes, I actually enter the value manually and there isn't any formatting in excel cell, I made sure of that too. I am still not sure what could cause this.

Comment: What's the Mule version? Did you install any patches?

Comment: No I don't have any patches, we are running lates mule version. Versioning is also not a problem since we have scheduled calls with Mule architects to review what we ve done (Due to the nature of the contract of our company with SF)

Comment: Is the value coming from the of the script you shared, or there is some further operation after that?

Comment: the value is coming from the script I shared, no other operations on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233795/discussion-between-aled-and-anxiousavocado).

Comment: @aled I opened file in notepad but still the same values as I am seeing in excel, only Mule is changing it while reading.

Answer (score 0):

Try typecasting to string then back to number such as this:

```
 %dw 2.0
output application/json

---

payload.parts pluck (value,key,index) -> 
        {
            (key) : { ((read(value.content, 'application/xlsx')) as String {format: "0:00"}) as Number
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue with excel,
Had solved it by type casting value to number then to String format

E.g.

```
{
 "Key" : value as Number as String { format: "##0.00" }
}
```

This maintained precision when genuinely there's a decimal.